# Having an issue solving a question pertaining to Partial Differential Equations.

Tags: calculus

Assume that the function $F(x,y,z)$ satisfies the equation 
$$\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{z}} = \frac{\partial^2{F}}{\partial{x}^2} + \frac{\partial^2{F}}{\partial{y}^2}$$ 
and 
$$\frac{\partial^2{F}}{\partial{x}\partial{y}} = \frac{\partial^2{F}}{\partial{y}\partial{x}}$$

Let $A$ be some constant and let $G(\gamma,s,t) = F(\gamma + s, \gamma - s, At)$. Find the value of A such that

$$\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{t}} = \frac{\partial^2{G}}{\partial{\gamma}^2} + \frac{\partial^2{G}}{\partial{s}^2}$$

I have this question assigned as practice for an upcoming quiz. I've spent the last couple of hours trying to solve it, but it hasn't gone so well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a matter of "solving" any differential equation but simply of **verifying** that the given function does satisfy the given equation. You do that by taking the derivatives and putting them into the equation.  For example, on the left you have $\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}$.  Since G is defined by $G(\gamma, s, t)= F(\gamma+ s, \gamma- s, At)$, by the chain rule, 
$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial t}= \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}= \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(0)+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(0)+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}(A)= A\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}$$

Similarly, 
$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial \gamma}= \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \gamma}+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \gamma}+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial \gamma}= \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(1)+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(1)+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}(0)= \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$$

And, 
$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial s}= \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial s}= \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(1)+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(-1)+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}(0)= \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}- \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$$

Put those into the equation and use the fact that F satisfies its equation to show that the "G" equation is satisfied.